# asp.net 5 DI: Using scoped service outside request

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

We have a IOrderManager service which uses some other services registered in DI via AddScoped().
Now we need to use that service in the OnMessage handler for some queue which, obviously, is raised outside any request pipeline. 
So when we try to get our service using something like

```
var orderManager = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOrderManager>();
```

we got "Can't access disposed object ..." exception.

Question: is it possible to "tell" DI that we are inside some "fake request" processing to avoid disposing services registered as "scoped"?

Comment: Give please bigger info. At the momoent question isn't clear. Where do you getting orderManager? Where is obtaining serviceProvider from?

Answer (score 3):

If your `IOrderManager` is outside request scope, you can create your custom scope per-message like this:

```
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
    var myService = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyService>();
}
```

Comment: There's an extension method, so you can shorten your code to `var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope()`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using scoped services within `IOrderManager`, `IOrderManager` needs to also be scoped.

If you don't do this, when the `IOrderManager` instance is first created, it will "capture" the scoped dependencies from the current request.

Any future usage of `IOrderManager` will continue to use the old scoped dependencies and not dependencies from the current request scope.

Next, the only reason you should use scoped dependencies is if they somehow maintain state across a single request and need to isolate that state from other requests.

If your `IOrderManager` doesn't actually need information that is scoped to a request, it shouldn't be scoped and shouldn't use dependencies that are also scoped.

Put another way, if you think it should be usable outside of an active request, it by definition is not scoped does not require scoped dependencies.